# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types when data table compute

Tags: c#

I want to sum a data table column that includes a filter. I am using the following code:

```
object sumTotal;
sumTotal = dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", "[emp Id]=5");
```

But I do not have an `empId` value of `5` in my database, so `dt.compute()` is not working. It shows an error:

> error message : Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Is there any method where if the `empId` of `5` cannot be found in my database, then it gives a result of `0`, and otherwise the sum total?

Comment: I have 3 column of my dB. Id, salary and emptype. I want to sum salary if employee type is 'A' with dt.compute method. But my dB has not any record of employee type 'A'. So I got the error. I want if no record of employee type 'A' sum results return as 0 otherwise shows the total salary of employee type 'A'.

Comment: Is the exception thrown on one of the above two lines? Or on a later line?

Answer (score 1):

The simple call to DataTable.Compute cannot give that error. If there is no EmpID with 5 as value the return of that call is DbNull.Value.

Of course, at this point, if you try to convert the result to some other type or cast it then you could get that error message.
You can avoid problems adding a check on the returned value

```
// Example for an int value returned by Compute
object sumTotal= dt.Compute("Sum(Total)", "[Emp ID] = 5");
int total = (sumTotal == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int)result);
Console.WriteLine(total);
```